# why Segmentation fault (core dumped ) occur while printing string?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

Why my code is giving Segmentation fault (core dumped ), I checked all possible test cases.

`Input: aaabbcc
 Output:abc`

`Input: abbcccccc
 Output:abc`

It will print only nonrepeated characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
char a[100],c=0;
int i;
scanf("%s",a);
for(i=0;a[i]!="\0";i++)
{
    if(a[i]!=a[i+1])
      printf("%c",a[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: If you intend to use `"` instead of `'`, do it right: `for(i=0;a[i] != *"\0" ;i++)` (or simply use `'` instead). Note that `for(i=0; a[i]!= *"";i++)` would also work.

Comment: Amazing, learned something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your for loop condition is wrong `a[i]!="\0"` should be `a[i]!='\0'`, you need to look for `'\0'` termination and `"\0"` is a string ( `char *` ) . Ideally with proper warnings you should have got compilation warnings.

```
for(i=0;a[i] != '\0';i++) 
{
    if(a[i]!=a[i+1])
      printf("%c",a[i]);
}
```

in fact a better for loop would be to guard against out of bounds in array sizes, for example consider a case where your input is more than `100` characters long

```
for(i=0; (a[i] != '\0' ) && ( i < (sizeof a) );i++)
{
    if(a[i]!=a[i+1])
      printf("%c",a[i]);
}
```